# Example of an equivlance relation that is transitive

Tags: self-learning, relations, equivalence-relations

I am just tying to figure our this example but am having difficulty understand the math being used.

The example state: Let R be a relation on the set $\mathbb{Z}$ defined as $(m,n)\in$ R if and only if $5|(m + 4n)$. We show first that $R$ is an equivalent relation.

(If you notice missing parts it is because I have already asked questions regarding this being reflexive and symmetric in another post.)

The example states: If $(m,n)$ and $(n,u)$ are in $R$, then $5k = m + 4n$ and $5s = n + 4u$ for some $k,s\in u$. Hence,

$$m + 4u = 5k - 4n + 5s - n = 5(k + s - n)$$
and $5|(m + 4u)$. Hence, $(m,u)\in $ R

I understand that the above equation is a combination of the two equations: $5k = m + 4n$ and $5s = n + 4u$ but, I don't understand why I can combine these two equations.

Continuing the example:
The equivalent classes are
$$[m]=\{{(n \in \mathbb{Z}|(m,n) \in R)}\} = \{n \in \mathbb Z|5|(m + 4n) \}.$$

Verify that 
$$ [0] = \{n \in \mathbb Z|5|4n\} = \{5k|k \in \mathbb Z\} $$
$$ [1] = \{n \in \mathbb Z|5|1 + 4n\} = \{1,6,11,16,...\} = \{1 + 5k|k \in \mathbb Z\} $$
$$ [2] = \{n \in \mathbb Z|5|2 + 4n\} = \{2,7,12,17,...\} = \{2 + 5k|k \in \mathbb Z\}. $$

I can see how $\{1,6,11,16,...\} = \{1 + 5k|k \in \mathbb Z \}$ is related. If I let k = 0, I get 1; If I let k = 1, I get 6, etc. But I don't see how 
$\{n \in \mathbb Z|5|1 + 4n\} = \{1,6,11,16,...\}$ is related. I've tried using 0, 1, and 2 for n but that does not work and, I'm not sure what I am missing.

There is another small part to this equation, but I would like to try and figure it out before posting it, if i have trouble with it.

Thanks for any help.

Tony

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you noticed that $5$ divides $m+4n$ if and only if $5$ divides $m-n$? This will make your calculations much easier. For instance, to show transitivity, if $5$ divides $m-n$ and $n-q$, then 
$$
5 \, | \, m-q = (m-n) + (n-q) 
$$
It also makes it more obvious now that the equivalence class of $1$ is just $1 + 5k$, since $(5k+1)-1$ is divisible by $5$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Hi, I am not completely clear on this yet but, I will take it and try to figure it out. I'm not sure of this part: 5 divides m+4n if and only if 5 divides m−n. Is this, 5|m−q=(m−n)+(n−q), because of it is transitive? I'll have to do more reading on this section, I believe. I was doing okay in the section of my study guide until I came across this example. Thanks for you feedback.

Comment: @Tony : The point is that $m+4n = m-n + 5n$, hence you can see that $5$ divides $m+4n$ if and only if it divides $m-n$, because the numbers $m+4n$ and $m-n$ differ by a multiple of $5$. My point was then that the proofs using the relation become much easier, such as the proof that this relation is transitive ; this is what I explained above, together with the proof that $[1] = \{\cdots,-4,1,6,11,16,\cdots\}$.